# Rails: How to error when two strong parameters are sent together at the same time? Allow one of them only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, parameters, strong-parameters

Let's say I accept two different parameters on input: `param1` and `param2` but I don't allow them to be passed together. How do I error in that case? I need to notify the client they are sending something wrong

```
params.require(:key).permit(
:other_param,
:param1 || :param2).to_hash
```

Thanks

Comment: So why don't you allow both the parameters and add validation on the model instead that both parameters are not set together?

Comment: because I have only ```param1``` column in my model and not ```param2``` plus it makes no sense to proceed any further if i know the client passed me the wrong batch of parameters I guess

Comment: Okay, so why would you permit `param2` in strong parameters in that case?

Comment: because my client might send either one so i'd store ```param2``` under ```param1``` with some modifications as they are slightly different but I don't allow them both and ```param2``` is a legacy one but need to support it still for a while. It's already all considered haha

Answer (score 0):

What about allowing them both and validates your logic in your controller?

```rb
  # When `param1` and `param2` are sent at the same time, 
  # a 400 - Invalid Request will be sent back to the client
  def hello
    hello_params = params.require(:key).permit(:param1, :param2)

    # Return 400 - Invalid Request if both params are present
    if hello_params[:param1] && hello_params[:param2]
      render json: { message: "Both param1 and param2 should not be sent together." }, status: 400
      return
    end

    render json: { message: "Hello, world!" }
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this. This will permit `:params1` if it is present in the params, `:param2` otherwise.

```
def key_params
  required_params = params.require(:key)

  attribute = required_params.key?(:param1) ? :params1 : :params2

  required_params.permit(:other_params, attribute)
end
```